# SQLite JDBC get on resultset always returns null resp. 0

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

In the following code, I execute a query on a SQLite JDBC connection via the `executeRestitutionalQuery(String query)` method:

```
public static ArrayList<Metadata> findMetadata(String name, String text, String after, String before, String repPath)
    throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

    ArrayList<Metadata> data = new ArrayList<Metadata>();
    boolean needADD = false;

    String query = "SELECT * from " + TABLE_NAME_METADATA;

    ...

    query += " ORDER BY timestamp DESC;";

    ResultBundle bundle = executeRestitutionalQuery(query);
    ResultSet result = bundle.getResultSet();

    while(result.next()){
        Metadata metadata = new Metadata(result.getLong("id"), result.getString("name"), Timestamp.valueOf(result.getString("timestamp")), 
                result.getInt("filesNo"), result.getLong("size"), result.getString("description"), -1);
        data.add(metadata);
    }

    closeStatementAndResultSet(bundle.getStatement(), bundle.getResultSet());

    return data;
}

private static ResultBundle executeRestitutionalQuery(String query) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{

    Connection connection = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet result = null;
    ResultBundle bundle = null;

    try{
        connection = getConnection();
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        statement.executeUpdate(query);
        connection.commit();

        result = statement.executeQuery(query);

        bundle = new ResultBundle(statement, result);

    }finally{

        if(connection != null){
            try{
                connection.close();
            }catch (Exception e){
                /* ignored */
            }
        }
    }

    return bundle;
}
private static void closeStatementAndResultSet(Statement statement, ResultSet result){
    if(result != null){
        try{
            result.close();
        }catch (Exception e){
            // ignored
        }
    }

    if(statement != null){
        try{
            statement.close();
        }catch (Exception e){
            // ignored
        }
    }
}
```

The `ResultBundle` class is just used to summarize the resultset and the statement. It looks like this:

```
public class ResultBundle {

private final Statement statement;
private final ResultSet result;

public ResultBundle(Statement statement, ResultSet result){
    this.result = result;
    this.statement = statement;
}

public Statement getStatement(){
    return statement;
}

public ResultSet getResultSet(){
    return result;
}
```

}

The problem is, that every call to `result.getLong()`, `result.getString()` etc. returns `null` resp. 0. I can't understand why. The queries should all be okay, as the code was running fine before I had to do some refactoring. Could the problem arise from the `ResultBundle`-class? What am I not seeing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Statement`s and `ResultSet`s are "live" objects, living only as long as their connection. The `executeRestitutionalQuery` returns a `ResultBundle`, whose `result` and `statement` members are implicitly closed on return when the connection is closed in the `finally` block.

```
try {

    ...

}finally{

    if(connection != null){
         try{
             connection.close();      // <---- here's the problem
         }catch (Exception e){
             /* ignored */
         }
     }
 }
```

By the time, the caller of `executeRestitutionalQuery` can lay its hand on the resource bundle, the connection has been closed, and the result set is "dead".

Answer (score 1):

I would say this is a bad design.

A better one would keep the SQL objects in tight scope, map results into a collection or object and immediately close all those scarce resources.  Not only will the data be available to clients, but you'll avoid nasty problems with connection and cursors exhausted.  It'll scale better, too.